# Exception : 'unicode' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python, csv, unicode, readlines

I passing a csv file path into this function.

```
def validateCSV(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        print type(filename)
        if not filename.readlines(): 
            print 'empty file'
        else:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                print row
    file.close()
```

but when I run this I got an error

'unicode' object has no attribute 'readlines'

but when I check the type of the csv file it is unicode. So I understood that they need a file object.So how can I convert unicode to file object.
Then i tried this,

```
filename = filename.encode("utf-8")
```

then its type becomes string and shows another error.

'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `filename` is not `file`

Comment: @PeterWood i didnt understand what u said.Please give me a detail

Comment: @PeterWood filname is a unicode object

Comment: replace ` if not filename.readlines(): ` with `if not file.readlines()` this is what Peter Wood means

Comment: But I cant read the file contensts

Comment: Sorry, but your code has multiple problems. You seem to misunderstand "open", the open-mode, the "with"-statement and "readlines"-function. Maybe you should take a step back and re-read the documentation or a tutorial of Python concerned with working with files.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `readline()` method from your file name which is certainly a Unicode object. If you want to check if your file is empty or not you can simply get the first row using `next` function and wrap it with a try-except statement:

```
def validateCSV(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          try:
              first_row = next(reader)   
          except StopIteration:
              print('empty file')
              return
          else:
              print(first_row)
              for row in reader:
                  print row
```

Also note that you don't need to close your file object when you are using `with` context manager. It will close the file at the end of the block automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to line :- `if not filename.readlines():` 
readlines() is a method present on file type object and not on string object.

```
def validateCSV(filename):
    #filename = filename.encode("utf-8")
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        print type(filename)
        if not file.readlines(): 
            print 'empty file'
        else:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                print row
    file.close()
```

Comment: Downvoter, specify reason for downvoting.

Comment: It was a code only answer and it wasn't obvious what you had fixed and why. Also, the question is a poor question, and is likely to be closed. It shouldn't really be answered as it stands.

Comment: Instead of discouraging answer writers, you must discourage person asking such questions.

Comment: @ManguSinghRajpurohit I agree with what you said about the discouragement.  Devoting you answer does not make sense to me.

Comment: The answer didn't explain the problems in the code. For example it is still incorrect as `file.readlines()` will read the whole file so there is nothing left for the `csv` reader to read. This is not a good answer. It is also up to you to ask the questioner to clarify their question and to encourage good questions.